# How to un-extract and re-extract Capistrano to the right place

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, capistrano

I'm getting this error when trying to do : `bundle exec cap deploy`

```
"RVM - Capistrano integration was extracted to a separate gem, \
install: `gem install rvm-capistrano` and remove the `$LOAD_PATH.unshift` line, \
note also the 'set :rvm_type, :user' is now the default (instead of :system)."
```

Unfortunately, none of those tips actually work.

The problem stems from when I had to revert my copy of RVM to an older copy to have it comply with POW. After I did this, this feature no longer worked. Which *sort of makes sense*.

So my question is simply, how do I re-engineer my Capistrano exactraction to **not a seperate gem**.

I tried uninstalling, everything, reinstalling everything, but that didn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem as you. In my deploy.rb file, I had to comment out this line:

```
$:.unshift(File.expand_path('./lib', ENV['rvm_path'])) # Add RVM's lib directory to the load path.
```

i.e.

```
# $:.unshift(File.expand_path('./lib', ENV['rvm_path'])) # Add RVM's lib directory to the load path.
```

Comment: This was totally the solution for me. The error message says "remove the `$LOAD_PATH.unshift` line", but it doesn't say where!

Answer (score 2):

RVM works with POW, this is known issue: https://github.com/37signals/pow/issues/271

the easiest solution(in project dir):

```
rvm env . > .powenv
```

Just go and use latest RVM, POW, rvm-capistrano gem - it should be working just fine.

Comment: Hmm.. your correction is for if i was trying to get RVM to work with POW with the latest addition. I'm not.  I had tried this though when I was trying to make them compatible and this didn't work. Right now I'm just trying to get the Capistrano gem to work. In my question, I mention that I've tried every possible solution presented in their failure response. :D

Comment: the old behavior (without gem `rvm-capistrano`) is no more supported by RVM, by choosing to stay with older version you lose possibility to get my help (I'm RVM maintainer).

Comment: Just an update. I reinstalled latest rvm (`1.13.0`) Using `rvm-capistrano` in my Gemfile ( this particular app does not use POW ), and I still get this error when trying to do `bundle exec cap deploy staging`. There is no `load_path` statement in my app. Can you think of anything else that might be a solution to this?

Comment: This is new problem, open a new question and include your deploy.rb